# maintain image position while scaling video

Tags: jquery, html, css, video, positioning

I have a few see-through click elements over a video.. when changing the aspect ratio of the browser the positioning of the elements messes up which causes click action to not happen when you click on an animation.

I use % but for some reason it still doesn't position it correctly on multiple screen sizes.

CSS:

```
#vidKlik1{
    width: 8%;
    height: 30%;
    top: 148%;
    left: 16%;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="popup">
        <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="background2">
            <source src="background/background2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </source>
            <source src="background/background2.ogv" type="video/ogg"> </source>
            <source src="background/background2.webm" type="video/webm"> </source>  
        </video>

        <a href="#popup-box" class="popup-window">
            <img src="images/klik.jpg" id="vidKlik1">
        </a>

        <a href="#popup-box" class="popup-window">
            <img src="images/klik.jpg" id="vidKlik2">
        </a>

        <a href="#popup-box" class="popup-window">
            <img src="images/klik.jpg" id="vidKlik3">
        </a>

        <a href="#popup-box" class="popup-window">
            <img src="images/klik.jpg" id="vidKlik4">
        </a>        
    </div>
```

and for some reason I also have to use top: 148% because if I take top: 100% it only positions it 50% from the top of the page, right in between 2 video's

Is there any way to fix this? I'am already using % but for some reason it just won't position the image correctly.. I've also tried using VH and VW, I just don't know which other things I could do to make the image always appear on a certain position when the video behind it scales.

In short: I have an image which I want to scale with the video behind it to make the video have clickable interactions, however it often goes too far down.

Comment: Could you please post some relevant code with the video. The solution is simple, your video and link needs to be in a container. The container then takes up the with and height of the video. The link is positioned on top of the video (position:absolute; z-index:1000) and it will reposition itself according to the container. I can give you an example but I need some code to work with.

Comment: @vyx.ca I've editted my question so that it has more code, however I tried doing what you've suggested as one of the first things, however it didn't work out as I wanted, perhaps I did something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on my comments, [here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masu1mko/2/)

CSS

```
.popup { 
  position:relative;
  width:75%;
}

.popup video { width:100%;}

.popup a { position:absolute; z-index:1000;}

#vidKlik1 { top:5%; left:5%; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="popup">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="background2">
        <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm"></source>
    </video> 

    <a href="#popup-box" class="popup-window" id="vidKlik1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    </a>
</div>
```

The important parts

- `popup` needs to be `position:relative`
- the `<a>` needs to have an *id* so you can position it independently of the others

Comment: Using your code sortof breaks the website, as in that my jQuery code doesn't turn my images visible.

Comment: @Gerwin They don't become visible because you are using the ids in your jQuery? If so, that's not a problem... keep the ids on the images and use other ids on the links. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/masu1mko/4/

Comment: They don't become visible using the following code, when removed they do become visible; .popup { 
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}

.popup video { width:100%;}

.popup a { position:absolute; z-index:1000;}

just changed .popup to #test and it fixed the issue

Comment: However the images do not maintain their positioning when I re-scale the window

Comment: @Gerwin If you look at my example, they do keep their position when the page rescales. You need to adapt your code. I was only given an example of what you have. In order to help you out more, I need the whole code... a link...

Comment: Could we talk about it in a discussion room?

Comment: is there any chance we could?

Comment: I have fixed the issue, .popup a { position:absolute; z-index:1000;} the absolute was the cause of the issue, as it was already in the code, thank you for your help sir!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can be inconsistent with how they behave when the screen resolution or orientation changes. For consistent behavior across browsers, you'll want to use jQuery (since you have it listed in your tags) to handle a resize event, and re-calculate your popup position based on the new window dimensions and/or video position.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this won't work because the screen's aspect ratio isn't exactly the same as the video, therefore the percentages aren't necessarily equivalent. When you resize the window, are there black bars on any side of the video? Those black areas will mess with your percentages.